# Visual Studio 2015: no puedo agregar un nuevo modelo desde ODBC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, odbc

Tengo una base de datos Ingres, a la cual necesito acceder desde una API Rest creada con Visual Studio.
Tengo instalado todo lo necesario en la PC de desarrollo:
Ingres Cliente completo + .Net Driver
Configurado el ODBC que apunta a la base de datos, testado y funcionando.

Cuando en VS2015 creo el proyecto, con el Explorador de Servidores agrego una conexion de datos al ODBC que cree, y el testeo funciona bien.
Cuando finalmente quiero agregar a Models la base de datos, no logro de ninguna manera que en el data source me aparezca el origen de datos ODBC que creer.
No tengo problemas cuando se trata de SQL Server, Oracle, Excel, Postgres o MySQL.
Alguien paso por lo mismo?
Gracias!

Comment: Usually you need a DDEX, (Data Designer Extensibility) for your database. Like Npgsql DDEX. http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html

Comment: Perdona, normalmente necesitas un DDEX (Extension de diseño de datos)  como el que instalas para Npgsql. http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html

Comment: mcNets, voy a revisar el link. Gracias.